# About HashMap collection's keySet() method

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator, keyset

```
Map<K, V> map = HashMap<K, V>();

Set<K> keySet = map.keySet(); //'map' is  parameter of HashMap object

Iterator<K> keyIterator = keySet.iterator();
```

---

I'm studying about how I can get key by 'Iterator'. The code above is part of that.

but `[Set<K> keySet = map.keySet();]` <- in this part

Isn't it that `HashMap`'s `keySet()` method is what `Set` interface's `keySet()` method is redefined in `HashMap`?

but I can't find it in JAVA API document's method menu.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking.  The `keySet()` method is documented to return an object which implements `Set`.  Are you asking exactly what the implementing class will be?

Comment: What do you mean you can't find it? It's right there in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be making this more complicated than necessary.

A Map<K,V> has some keys; it will hand you a view of those keys as a Set<K>.

That Set<> necessarily implements the Set<> interface, which has Iterable<> as a subinterface.  Therefore you can get an iterator over the Set.

Since it's an Iterator, then if you iterate it, it will eventually yield every possible key.   That is:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     key = iterator.Next(); // <<< this is the key
      :
}
```

But what are you actually trying to do?

> i'm studying about how i can get key by 'iterator' above is part of
> that

The point of the Map and Set interfaces is that you can access them directly by key.

Answer (score 0):

The `keySet()` method returns a set of keys in the `HashMap` of type `KeySet`. The inner implementation in the HashMap implements `AbstractSet` and stores the keys into that set with the name of `keySet`.

The hierarchy of the implementations in the `HashMap`:

```
|---- Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>
|
|------- Set<E> extends Collection<E>
|
|------------ AbstractSet<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements Set<E>
|
|--------------- KeySet extends AbstractSet<K>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do that.  But I have never had the need to get the `keySet` iterator.  You can just do the following.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
// later
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
   // so something with keys (e.g) print them.
   System.out.println(key);
}
```

But you can also do this.

```
Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```